# Postgres nested loop not used in recursive query

Tags: postgresql, recursion, nested, nested-loops, sql-execution-plan

Bad execution plan on simple recursive query.
Vacuum and analyse performed.
Why merge join is used instead of nested loop?

On table plm.link_plm statistics ok.

```
vacuum analyze plm.link_plm.
```

Table size

```
select count(*) from plm.link_plm
-- 12s -> 69568347 rows.
```

Test with and without nested loop

```
set enable_hashjoin to on;
set enable_mergejoin to on;

with recursive r as (
    select l.* from plm.link_plm l where l.ci = 14546722
    union all select l.* from r join plm.link_plm l on l.ci = r.pi
) select distinct * from r;
-- merge join used, duration more than 1 hour
```

below the execution plan:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
    Group Key: r.pi, r.ci, r.name, r.type, r.matrix, r.wipfirst, r.relfirst, r.partition, r.j
  CTE r
      ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on link_plm l  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
                    Recheck Cond: (ci = 14546722)
                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on link_plm_ci_pi_idx  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
                          Index Cond: (ci = 14546722)
            ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
                  ->  Sort  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
                          Sort Key: r_1.pi
                        ->  WorkTable Scan on r r_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
                  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
                        ->  Sort  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
                                Sort Key: l_1.ci
                              ->  Seq Scan on link_plm l_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
  ->  CTE Scan on r r  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
```

```
set enable_hashjoin to off;
set enable_mergejoin to off;

with recursive r as (
    select l.* from plm.link_plm l where l.ci = 14546722
    union all select l.* from r join plm.link_plm l on l.ci = r.pi
) select distinct * from r;
-- nested loop on index used, duration 0.1s
```

Comment: Don't forget to ask the question. If it's going to be *"why is the first score this much worse"*, expect a request for table, index and statistics definitions, detailed output of the `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)` you're referring to, possibly [pasted here](https://explain.depesz.com/).

Comment: The question is: why merge join is used instead of nested loop? I add the execution plan of the merge join, the merge join lasts 1 hour, the nested loop 0.1s.

Comment: Looks like your testing on an empty table, any query plan is fine: `rows=0`. By the way, without `(analyze, verbose, buffers)` you only get a query plan from explain, but all the details and the execution will be missing.

Comment: I think, the choice between using a merge join and a nested loop in PostgreSQL's query planner is influenced by the estimated cost of each operation, which is based on the statistics gathered by ANALYZE.. The difference in execution times you've observed suggests that, the nested loop join is far more efficient, likely due to the specific access patterns and the effectiveness of using indexes with the nested loop join. It's also possible that the recursive nature of the query makes the cost estimation particularly challenging, leading to less optimal plan choices by the query planner.

Comment: Your plan seems to have been stripped of all useful information.  I don't know how you managed that.

Comment: Pls post the *real* output of `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`  for **both queries**. In the first line you should observe something like: `HashAggregate  (cost=261036.34..261037.35 rows=101 width=40) (actual time=1551.874..1551.881 rows=10 loops=1)`  - your *single* post seems to be *faked* with *zeroes*.